# Stop jQuery event propagation for specific event handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm attempting to stop event propagation only for a specific event handler, while allowing others on the same event to propagate, here is an example:

```
function Control(parent) {
    this.Parent = $(parent);
    this.Parent.append('<div class="test"></div>');
    this.Test = $('.test', this.Parent).last();
    this.Test.bind('mousedown', this, Control_All);
    this.Test.bind('mousedown', this, Control_Top);
}
function Control_All(event) {
    //this should bubble up through both c1 and c2
}
function Control_Top(event) {
    //this should stop at c2
}
Control.prototype.constructor = Control;
Control.prototype.All = Control_All;
Control.prototype.Top = Control_Top;

var c1 = new Control('body');
var c2 = new Control(c1.Test);
```

In the example above `c1.Test` and `c2.Test` are the same size.  I am attempting to make a `mousedown` event call these three events (I'm aware that the OO methodology isn't maintained and state is kept via `event.data`, but am using OO notation for simplicity, in my actual use case the All and Single delegates are bound variable orders and only in some instances, so the order in which they are bound cannot be controlled):

c1.All
c2.All
c2.Single

I've attempted `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `return(false)` at the end of `Control_Top`, but none work to do as described above.

Edit: [Here is a JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryG/cvmEz/) to assist anyone interested in helping with it.

Edit again: Solved using a global and an extra bind to `body.mousedown`, [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryG/DeFj5/) if anyone needs it, would welcome a solution that doesn't use a global or an extra binding.

Comment: There's only one "event" happening. The event bubbles, not the event handler. If you stop the propagation of the event, it won't propagate to either handler. Just make your handlers more specific so that they only handle the event at the point you want them to handle it.

Comment: Kevin, I solved it after your response and posted the solution in an edit, in my specific case the events are actually bound to a control from two different points (one internally that should bubble up, and one externally that should only be called once in spite of the fact controls can be nested inside of eachother, but listens on every control within a page).  The global+extra bind solution I came up with feels a bit kludgy, but it works and I need to move on to the next part of this.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/cvmEz/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just confirm that the event target is equal to the element you bound the event to.

http://jsfiddle.net/cvmEz/2/

```
function Control(parent,name) {
    this.Parent = $(parent);
    this.Parent.append('<div class="test" data-name="' + name + '"></div>');
    this.Test = $('.test', this.Parent).last();
    this.Test.bind('mousedown', this, Control_All);
    this.Test.bind('mousedown', this, Control_Top);
}
function Control_All(event) {
  if ( event.target == this) {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-name') + '.All');
  }
}
function Control_Top(event) {
  if ( event.target == this) {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-name') + '.Top');
  }
}
Control.prototype.constructor = Control;
Control.prototype.All = Control_All;
Control.prototype.Top = Control_Top;

var c1 = new Control('body', 'c1');
var c2 = new Control(c1.Test, 'c2');

console.log('--------');
```